# jQuery validation: no error being generated, doesn't prevent submission (i.e. is not working)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I just can't see what's wrong with this - if any fresh pairs of eyes could assist I'd be very grateful. Here is the whole lot (although I've stripped it down to be just one question etc).

I used google's address as the action address just to test it in js fiddle (where it does nothing) the real version points to page two of the form.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" >

<head>

    <!--jquery-->
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--jquery-->

    <!--jquerytools-->
    <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
    <!--jquerytools--->

</head>

<body>


<form id="form1" method="post" action="http://www.google.com">


                    <label for="question1">How Many?</label> 
                    <input     
                        title="Answer this" 
                        type="number"  
                        id="question1" 
                        name="question1" 
                        value="$question1" 
                        size="10" 
                        maxlength="10"

                    />

                    <input 
                    type="submit" 
                    value="Continue" 
                />
         </form>
<script>
(function($,W,D)
{
    var VALIDATE = {};

    VALIDATE.UTIL =
    {
        setupFormValidation: function()
        {
            //form validation rules
            $("#form1").validate({
                rules: {
                    question1: "required"                    
                    }

                messages: {
                    question1: "Please complete this field",
                    },
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    form.submit();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    //when the dom has loaded setup form validation rules
    $(D).ready(function($) {
        VALIDATE.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
    });

})(jQuery, window, document);
</script>    

</body>
</html>
```

I'm using the method described here:
http://www.jquery4u.com/forms/basic-jquery-form-validation-tutorial/#.UE6tb41lTwk

where this validation is working fine - I am new to JS. All help much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: try enclosing script like this <script type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code has syntax error. check this **[*fiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/ScwLn/1/)**

```
(function($,W,D)
{
    var VALIDATE = {};

    VALIDATE.UTIL =
    {
        setupFormValidation: function()
        {
            //form validation rules
            $("#form1").validate({
                rules: {
                    question1: "required"                    
                    },//---------->your code was missing this comma
                messages: {
                    question1: "Please complete this field",
                    },
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    form.submit();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    //when the dom has loaded setup form validation rules
    $(D).ready(function($) {
        VALIDATE.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
    });

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Second thing to keep in mind is to initially include the jquery library and then the validate plugin like

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Also thanks for the tip about order of library inclusion - why is that necessary (out of interest)?

Comment: @Gideon because it is the basic jquery library and your plugins may require many functions which is defined in library. So when your plugins calls a function it should be defined earlier otherwise it will give an error